# Copy File from UNC Path Server - Using Delphi 7 Services

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I created one service which is running in one server and I need to copy directory from another server to directory in this server through this service. The service is failed when finding directory specified in another server. Like If `DirectoryExists("\\ServerName\DirectoryName")`. It is not working even, I set up the service with Network Authority.

Please give solution for this. It will be helpful.

Mallik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible explanation is that the service runs as a user that does not have read rights to the other server's volumes. Authenticating with NETWORKSERVICE does not help you. That's just a user that has access to TCP etc.

What you need to do is to run your service as a user which has read access to the other server's volumes. As a test try your personal login, but in the longer run you may wish to use a dedicated user just for this task.